# Different styles between citations and bibliography

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, citing

I know, it's ridiculous, but it's what my publisher asked me.
I should produce citations with the author names in normal text, and a bibliography with author names in small caps.
I really have no idea about how to produce such an inconsistency. Any help is appreciated.
Here's my MWE:

```
% !TEX TS-program = XeLaTeX
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode

\begin{filecontents}{archivio.bib}


@book{Hal:Sul,
    Address = {Vindobonae},
    Editor = {C. Halm},
    Number = {1},
    Publisher = {C. Geroldi filium bibliopolam academiae},
    Series = {\textsc{csel}},
    Title = {Sulpici Severi libri qui supersunt},
    Year = {1866}}


\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[11pt, openany]{book}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[babelshorthands=true]{italian}
\setotherlanguages{latin, english, french}

%%% bibliografia
\usepackage[babel,italian=guillemets]{csquotes}

\usepackage[    style=verbose-trad2,            
            language=italian,
            useprefix=true,                 
            firstinits=true,    
            citepages=omit,                 
            backend=biber,  
        ]{biblatex} 


\addbibresource{archivio.bib}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

\cite[55]{Hal:Sul} 

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it with the hook `\AtBeginBibliography`:

```
\AtBeginBibliography{\renewcommand{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{\textsc{#1}}}
```

A full MWE:

```
\begin{filecontents}{archivio.bib}
@book{Hal:Sul,
    Address = {Vindobonae},
    Editor = {C. Halm},
    Number = {1},
    Publisher = {C. Geroldi filium bibliopolam academiae},
    Series = {\textsc{csel}},
    Title = {Sulpici Severi libri qui supersunt},
    Year = {1866}}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[11pt, openany]{book}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[babelshorthands=true]{italian}
\setotherlanguages{latin, english, french}

%%% bibliografia
\usepackage[babel,italian=guillemets]{csquotes}

\usepackage[    style=verbose-trad2,            
            language=italian,
            useprefix=true,                 
            firstinits=true,    
            citepages=omit,                 
            backend=biber,  
        ]{biblatex} 

\AtBeginBibliography{\renewcommand{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{\textsc{#1}}}

\addbibresource{archivio.bib}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

\cite[55]{Hal:Sul} 

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 4):

I think you could insert

```
\renewcommand{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{\textsc{#1}}
```

before `\printbibliography`.

As moewe said in comment, the disadvantage of this approach is that it is not grouped. If you were to cite something after `\printbibliography` (even if it is not likely) it would get small caps as well. gusbrs's solution is better.

```
\begin{filecontents}{archivio.bib}
@book{Hal:Sul,
    Address = {Vindobonae},
    Editor = {C. Halm},
    Number = {1},
    Publisher = {C. Geroldi filium bibliopolam academiae},
    Series = {\textsc{csel}},
    Title = {Sulpici Severi libri qui supersunt},
    Year = {1866}}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[11pt, openany]{book}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[babelshorthands=true]{italian}
\setotherlanguages{latin, english, french}

%%% bibliografia
\usepackage[babel,italian=guillemets]{csquotes}

\usepackage[    style=verbose-trad2,            
            language=italian,
            useprefix=true,                 
            firstinits=true,    
            citepages=omit,                 
            backend=biber,  
        ]{biblatex} 

\addbibresource{archivio.bib}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

\cite[55]{Hal:Sul} 

\renewcommand{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{\textsc{#1}}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Citation:

[image]

Bibliography:

[image]

Comment: oops, simultaneous...

Comment: The disadvantage of this approach is that it is not grouped. If you were to cite something after `\printbibliography` it would get small caps as well.

Comment: I don't want to pressure anyone into doing that. I just wanted to point out the difference between the two solutions. Since it is quite unlikely that someone would `\cite` after `\printbibliography`, your solution will still do the right thing for most intents and purposes.